# MS Powerpoint - summarisation via VBA function

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint

**Problem description:**

I have power point presentation. Each slide has same layout with different text. The goal is to automatically summarise information from each slide to be sent via email.

**Limitations:**

- I am not much limited in updating slide meta informations or even visual layout or changing to the table form

**Output:**

- from each slide a headline information and text from one defined textbox to be outputted to email.

**Example:**

- Three slides with headlines: Issue 1, Issue 2 and Different Stuff
- Each slide contains text box with issue summary
- Output:

```
     - Issue 1: summary information of issue 1
     - Issue 2: summary information of issue 2
     - Different Stuff: summary information of different stuff
```

**Questions:**

- How to loop through presentation and pick up information from specific textbox / headline?
- How to mark objects with text for processing via VBA? (I know how to name object like Text Field, but the name has to be unique.)

Comment: Is this a request for us to write code for you? I normally charge for that service

Comment: There are some examples of exporting various types of text to file here:
https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00274_Export_Text_to_a_text_file-_extract_text_from_PowerPoint_-Mac_or_PC-.htm  
(You'll need to copy the entire URL and paste it into your browser; SO's version of the link doesn't work"

Comment: @CHill60: Thank you for comment. I added the questions to the end. I do not know how to mark the objects a loop them within document.

Comment: You can use Tags to mark the shapes and later locate them specifically.  There are examples here:  https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00815_Working_with_Tags_-and_a_bit_about_Functions-.htm